# Linked-list logical errors causes program to freeze

Tags: c, debugging, pointers, linked-list, runtime-error

I'm trying to create the classic game of Snake (in a Linux terminal) but I'm having issues with either my linked list and/or basic logical implementation. I'm fairly certain that my move_snake() method is correct- however, upon completion of grow_snake(), which adds the same number of nodes as the value of the trophy retrieved, the program freezes. I have a feeling this is because of how I allocate my pointer(s) in the grow_snake() class, specifically after adding to the head of the snake, but I've been having such difficulty that I could really use another pair of eyes at this point. Thanks in advance.

**move_snake()**

```
// Moves the snake based on user input, via key press
void move_snake(){
    struct snake_struct *temp_ptr = root;
    struct snake_struct *last_node = malloc(sizeof(struct snake_struct *));
    change_direction(ui);                                   // Change direction on UI
    draw_border();                                          // Clear screen & draw border
    draw_trophy();                                          // Keep trophy on screen

//    grow_snake();
    check_position();

    while(temp_ptr->next){
        mvaddch(temp_ptr->y_pos, temp_ptr->x_pos, DEFAULT_SYMBOL);
        last_node = temp_ptr;
        temp_ptr = temp_ptr->next;
    }

    temp_ptr->x_pos = root->x_pos + x_dir;
    temp_ptr->y_pos = root->y_pos + y_dir;
    if(root->next != NULL)
        temp_ptr->next = root;
    last_node->next = NULL;
    root = temp_ptr;


    mvaddch(root->y_pos, root->x_pos, set_symbol());
    refresh();
    usleep(speed);
}
```

**grow_snake()**

```
// Grows the snake based on trophy value that was ate
void grow_snake(){

struct snake_struct *temp_ptr = root;
struct snake_struct *new_head = malloc(sizeof(struct snake_struct *));
change_direction(ui);                                   // Change direction on UI
//    int num_links = 2;
int num_links = trophy.value;
generate_trophy();
int i = 0;
draw_border();                                          // Clear screen & draw border
draw_trophy();                                          // Keep trophy on screen

    while(temp_ptr->next){
        mvaddch(temp_ptr->y_pos, temp_ptr->x_pos, DEFAULT_SYMBOL);
        temp_ptr = temp_ptr->next;
    }

for(i = 0; i < num_links; i++) {
    new_head->x_pos = root->x_pos + x_dir;
    new_head->y_pos = root->y_pos + y_dir;
    new_head->next = root;
    new_head->symbol = DEFAULT_SYMBOL;
    root = new_head;
    set_symbol();
    change_direction(ui);
    mvaddch(root->y_pos, root->x_pos, root->symbol);
    refresh();
    usleep(speed);
    }
}
```

**change_direction()**

```
// Changes direction on user key input
void change_direction(char key_press){
    if ((char) tolower(key_press) == 'w'){
        if(y_dir == 1 && root->next){
            alert(2);
        }
        else{
            y_dir = -1;
            x_dir = 0;
        }
    }
    else if ((char) tolower(key_press) == 'a'){
        if(x_dir == 1 && root->next){
            alert(2);
        }
        else{
            y_dir = 0;
            x_dir = -1;
        }
    }
    else if ((char) tolower(key_press) == 's'){
        if(y_dir == -1 && root->next){
            alert(2);
        }
        else{
            y_dir = 1;
            x_dir = 0;
        }
    }
    else if ((char) tolower(key_press) == 'd'){
        if(x_dir == -1 && root->next){
            alert(2);
        }
        else{
            y_dir = 0;
            x_dir = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `grow_snake()` function, your `malloc()` call is not allocating the proper amount of bytes. By writing :

```
malloc(sizeof(struct snake_struct *));
```

you are allocating the size of a pointer to your structure instead of allocating the size of the structure itself. Remove the " * " and try with

```
malloc(sizeof(struct snake_struct));
```

Comment: Yeah- that small change literally pretty much fixed everything. I can't believe I didn't catch that myself, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is, that you would have to create a new_head in each iteration in grow_snake.
e.g. move

```
struct snake_struct *new_head = malloc(sizeof(struct snake_struct *));
```

directly after the

```
for(i = 0; i < num_links; i++) {
```

Comment: I had a feeling this was the issue as well so I had moved the memory allocation for this pointer last night but I guess the change wasn't reflected in the code I posted here. With that being said, the program still adds the appropriate number of segments and then freezes, rather than continuing to move the snake as anticipated. Definitely appreciate the advice though, thanks again!